# fixing header width due to lower table stretch

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a fluid layout.  Header has a background repeater 1x100 png on the div.
it fills to the right of the view port as desired.

However, there's also a data table on this page in the mainbody div.  And, on most viewports, it causes horizontal scrolling because there's so much stuff in it.

When scrolled to the right, the header is not there.

Is there a way with jquery, or otherwise, to cause the header to stretch to the width of the table?   I won't know how big the table is until it's rendered.  I tried hacking it with 110% and other widths, but its never accurate depending on content as the table is fluid with nowhitespace linebreaks either, and longer titles stretch cells.

This is an ie8 intranet, so any fix must work in this browser.

html is very basic and pseducode looks like

```
<div id=wrap>
<div id=header></div>
<div id=tablearea><table>WIDE TABLE HERE</table></div>
</div>
```

I was hoping the wrapper would stretch on resize, but it doesn't.

any tips to get that header to paint right?  I'd love to use straight CSS, but am not opposed to a javascript/jquery hack.

Again, ie8 is our line (unfortunately) so it must work on that.

I made a quick paint jobber, but all the imgur, tinypic, etc sites are blocked at the office so i can't seem to get it hosted anywhere.   if anyone has any tips on that too would be appreciated (via pm).

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe post an [Jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) It helps us to think more logic about it.

Comment: i'd love to, but it's blocked.  work filter is tough.  as above, the markup is simple.  no floats or anything, just 2 main divs.  header has a bg repeat-x.  table has 15 + td cells, all with lots of non-wrapping text, so it gets wide.   header doesn't fill the expanded right stretch over 100%.

Comment: Do you have it online? so you can post the website.

Comment: No, it is an intranet only site. sorry.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a work around in place now.  I moved the bg off the header and put it directly on the body tag itself.  Seems to work ok.


Now, to figure out how to make the footer div do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/cZ9Vu/1

```
#wrap, #tablearea {overflow-x: auto;}
```